# autoloder не находит класс (use composer)

Tags: php, composer, autoload

использую composer не находит класс

```
<?php 

namespace App;

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use App\Model\I_Model\ProductModel;
use App\Model\Disc_Model\Disc;


$model = new ProductModel;
$model->hello();
$disc = new Disc;
$disc->hello();

?>
```

ProductModel работает, Disc нет, ошибка Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Model\Disc_Model\Disc' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\TestTask\index.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\TestTask\index.php on line 12

Comment: Покажи свою структуру папок и файлов.

Comment: Перезапустил композер и заново прописал пути, пересаздовал папки, скорее всего была ошибка с папками